# GNU make - how to set an implicit pattern as a prerequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this implicit rule:

```
%.so: %.so.5
    qnx_ln $< $@
```

I realized that for another target, I have to make all `.so` files the prerequisite for that target.

I tried this:

```
makegen: $(TEAM_ROOT)HMI_FORGF/src/src.pro module_dirs %.so
    ...
```

But I got the output

> *** No rule to make target '%.so', needed by 'makegen'.  Stop.

Comment: How would make know which .so file it needs if they don't exist at the time you build ? You're basically telling make "For the target makegen you need some .so files, deal with it". You have to give it a variable which contains the name of all the .so files required.

Comment: The %.so target could be translated like this : "For any .so file you meet, you need that and you do that". Here your makegen target would be "For makegen, you need that and any .so file". It does not make sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a Makefile target depend on pattern prerequisites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829344/how-to-set-a-makefile-target-depend-on-pattern-prerequisites)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` prerequisite patterns can only be used in static and implicit **pattern** rules, where they match the respective `%` part of the target; when used in a regular rule `%` is a literal character.

You'll need to specify the dependencies literally, unless there is some correspondence between certain source filenames and the `.so` filenames that you can leverage, presumably you're already doing either of these to link the `.so` files in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out previously, no you can't do that because this is not how prerequisite patterns work. Maybe you gave the following a thought and rejected it but I suspect you might find the following a close-enough fit:

```
%.so.target: %.so.5
        echo $< >> $(BUILD)/so.targets

SO_TARGETS=$(basename $(shell cat $(BUILD)/so.targets))

makegen: $(TEAM_ROOT)HMI_FORGF/src/src.pro module_dirs $(SO_TARGETS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a rule to match on every existing *.so file?

```
makegen: $(TEAM_ROOT)HMI_FORGF/src/src.pro module_dirs $(wildcard *.so)
    ...
```

However, if there are patterns which *could* generate *.so files which have not yet generated those files, they will (obviously) not be matched by the wildcard, which simply examines existing files.  If that's what you actually want to accomplish, you'll probably want to enumerate the actual files, one way or another.