# How to set a Makefile target depend on pattern prerequisites?

Tags: makefile

I have a chain of pattern dependencies in a makefile, and in the end they should come together in one file, e.g.: `*.x` -> `*.y` -> `onefile.z`

So I made the files like this:

```
$ touch a.x b.x
```

and the rules:

```
%.y: %.x some-other-script
    touch $@

onefile.z: %.y second-other-script
    touch $@
```

This rule does not work:

```
$ make onefile.z
make: *** No rule to make target '%.y', needed by 'onefile.z'.  Stop.
```

Using a wildcard:

```
%.y: %.x some-other-script
    touch $@

z: $(wildcard *.y) second-other-script
    touch $@
```

This does not work either: it sees there are no `*.y` files and proceeds making `onefile.z` skipping the first rule.

```
$ make onefile.z
touch onefile.z

$ ls
a.x b.x onefile.z Makefile
```

I probably could merge two rules into one, but in the real application, there are more steps, and some are making requests over HTTP and take much time, and in fact should not be repeated without a reason.

Is there a way to make such a dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onefile.z: %.y second-other-script` is a regular rule, not a pattern rule or a static pattern rule, so the `%` is interpreted literally. Even if it were a pattern rule, how is make supposed to infer what the stem is supposed to match?

`$(wildcard *.y)` tells make to find all the files that match `*.y`, but of course there are none yet so it returns an empty string.

The following should work, if I've understood your question correctly:

```
xfiles := $(wildcard *.x)
yfiles := $(xfiles:.x=.y)

%.y: %.x some-other-script
    touch $@

onefile.z: $(yfiles) second-other-script
    touch $@
```

See the Gnu Make documentation on

- Wildcard functions [`$(wildcard ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-wildcard_002c-function)
- Substitution functions [`$(foo:from=to)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-modified-variable-reference)

Comment: That did work, thanks a lot! (although SO turns linebreaks into something that breaks formatting, made me puzzled for a while)